# nodejs/bin/node does't exists when truing to install node.js on server

Tags: node.js

I have shaed hosting on siteground , basically my server runs PHP , but i also wanted to run node on my server , so i `ssh'ed` using putty and ran the following commands:

1. `curl http:// nodejs.org/dist/latest/node-v8.11.3-linux-x64.tar.xz`  Then unzipped it.
2. `mv node-v8.11.3-linux-x64/ nodejs`.
3. `mkdir ~/bin`
4. `cp nodejs/bin/node ~/bin`

The last command throws an error

> cp: connot stat `nodejs/bin/node:` no such file or directory exists

I was basically trying to follow the tutorial on [HERE](https://medium.com/@andreacannella/how-to-install-node-js-on-siteground-shared-hosting-527d9ddeb5ae).

Comment: Did you also untar the archive?  The command it lists is `curl http://nodejs.org/dist/latest/node-vMAJOR.MINOR.PATCH-linux-x64.tar.gz  | tar xz` which pipes the download through tar.  I don't see that listed in the steps in your question.

Answer (score -1):

Follow this guide instead, it's from the actual node GitHub instead of a Medium article: [How to install Node.js via binary archive on Linux?](https://github.com/nodejs/help/wiki/Installation).

You are going to need 3 specific programs:

1. curl to download stuff
2. tar to deal with tar files
3. xz to deal with zip compression

Make sure all of those are installed using (and this assumes you're using Ubuntu or a distro that leverages apt):

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y curl tar xz-utils
```

After that do something a little bit different from the tutorial

1. Download and **save** the archive:

```sh
curl -O https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.11.3/node-v8.11.3-linux-x64.tar.xz
```

2. Untar the archive:

```sh
tar xf node-v8.11.3-linux-x64.tar.xz
```

3. Make a nodejs directory to organize your versions:

```sh
mkdir /usr/local/lib/nodejs
```

4. Move the unarchived folder to your `/usr/local/lib/nodejs` folder:

```sh
mv node-v8.11.3-linux-x64 /usr/local/lib/nodejs/
```

5. Symlink node and npm into the `/usr/bin/` folder:

```sh
ln -s /usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v8.11.3-linux-x64/bin/node /usr/bin/node
ln -s /usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v8.11.3-linux-x64/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm
```

6. Make sure everything is working:

```sh
node -v
npm -v
```